# Нужно реализовать программу, которая выдает числа с суммой цифр, равной 15 (69,78,87...)

Tags: c#

*Напишите программу, которая выведет все целые числа в диапазоне от 0 (включительно) до 999 (включительно) сумма цифр которых равна 15 (например, 717 должно быть выведено, ведь 7 + 1 + 7 = 15, 556 - нет, потому 5+ 5 + 6 = 16) в порядке возрастания (69 78 87 96 159 ...). Каждое число выведите в новой строке.*

**Моя попытка:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int n = i % 15;
                Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Мое решения** - не самый хороший вариант, но все же робочий, хотелось бы найти более оптимальной)) 
Спасибо за подсказку – @tym32167

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (100 > i)
            {
                int k = i % 10; 
                int j = i / 10;

                int sum = k + j;

                if (15 == sum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                }
            }
            else if (100 < i)
            {
                int kk = i % 10;
                int jj = i / 10;
                int kkk = jj % 10;
                int jjj = jj / 10;
                int kkkk = jjj % 10;

                int sum = kk + kkk + jjj;

                if (15 == sum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Моя попытка` - честно сказать я думаю это не попытка, а просто что-то написано, чтобы не придрались "а что вы пытались делать", но в итоге именно ждете, чтобы вам написали код

Comment: чтобы получить цифры от числа, надо получать остаток от деления на 10, а потом делить число на 10 нацело и снова получать остаток от деления на 10. Когда получите все остатки - складываете и проверяете сумму на равенство 15.

Comment: @tym32167 а почему на 10 ?

Comment: @tym32167 проще конвертировать в строку, а потом пробегаться посимвольно конвертируя в число

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в плане количества строк может и проще, а по скорости работы \ памяти - вот вопрос. Ну и это же лаба какая то, я так понимаю. Раз такое задание - наверняка они там деления проходят.

Comment: Остаток от деления на 10 надо получать, так как вы смотрите на число в десятичной системе. То есть 567%10=7, то есть последняя цифра. Потом делите 567/10=56, 56%10=6, потом снова делите 56/10=5, ну и 5%10=5. Таким образом мы получили все цифры числа.

Answer (score 5):

Ну например так:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(n => n.ToString()).Where(s => s.Sum(c => c - '0') == 15)));
```

Comment: что то мне не понятно, вы это всерьез предлагаете или троллите :)

Comment: @tym32167 судя по шапочке - шутит)

Comment: https://ideone.com/6hEZ6u - чтоб было, с чем ответ сверять)

Comment: У меня интереснее решение, хотя и без linq :D

Comment: Кстати, можно же сразу Where без Select: https://ideone.com/FxmK6b `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(n => n.ToString().Sum(c => c - '0') == 15)));`

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня так и было в первоначальном варианте, но я решил, что перевести в строки и работать с ними прикольнее.

Comment: Возможно даже, что немного оптимальнее, чтоб два раза не преобразовывать те, что будут выводиться %)

Answer (score 4):

Элегантное решение:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int shift1 = 63;
        int shift2 = 3;
        bool reverse = false;

        int i = 69;

        while (i < 1000) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

            for (int k = 0; k < shift2; ++k) {
                i += 9;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            i += shift1;

            shift2 += reverse ? -1 : 1;

            if (shift1 == 18 && !reverse) {
                reverse = true;
                shift1 -= 9;
            }

            shift1 -= reverse ? -9 : 9;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Первое число 89 не подходит.

Comment: @VladD Ааа, 15, точно. Чего-то прочитал 17

Comment: Если исправить на 69, выдаёт слишком много, подправляйте!

Comment: Да, правлю, сейчас изменю

Comment: @VladD теперь все хорошо)

Comment: `if (shift1 == 18 && !reverse)` :) А что, работает!

Comment: @VladD оно основано на разности между двумя соседними числами, сумма цифр которых будет 15. Разности: 9 9 9 63 9 9 9 9 54 5x9 45 и так далее) Вот только где-то посередке они начинают идти в обратную сторону, поэтому там флаг `reverse`)

Comment: Ага, я понял :) Интересная идея, да.

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/NSvUkh

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int x = 6, y = 9;

    do
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", x, y);
      if (--y == -1) y = 15 - (x += 10 - x % 10) / 10;
      else if (++x % 10 == 0) { x += y; y = 9; }
    } while (x < 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: [внезапный-codegolf]?

Comment: Понял, прикольное решение!

Comment: @VladD, еле получилось такое нагородить)))

Answer (score 3):

Всё-таки серьёзный ответ.

Ваша проблема сводится к нахождению цифр числа. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
IEnumerable<int> ReverseDigits(int n, int b = 10)
{
    if (b < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("WAT?");
    if (n == int.MinValue)
    {
        yield return -(n % b);
        n = n / b;
    }
    n = Math.Abs(n);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        yield return n % b;
        n = n / b;
    }
}
```

Имея набор цифр, подсчитать сумму и проверить её тривиально. Дерзайте!

Comment: Но я бы не считал сумму цифр числа в решении :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, то, что хочет лектор — нахождение всех цифр и суммирование, как я понимаю. Но да, два верхних решения обходятся без этого, потому что это _скучно_.

Comment: Хм, а что такое `b`? И что значит возвращаемая последовательность `0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1` при вызове `ReverseDigits(1010, 2)`?

Comment: @Андрей `Хм, а что такое b`...b сокращение от base. `И что значит возвращаемая последовательность` ToBin().Reverse()

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, ага, я понял. Мы передаем число и основание системы счисления, функция возвращает цифры этого числа в указанной системе счисления, просто меня смутило, что передаем int, а не представление числа в этой СС, например, как string. Теперь всё встало на свои места :)

Answer (score 3):

Нормальное решение: <s>https://ideone.com/q9bAde</s> https://ideone.com/ku9p84

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    for (int a=0; a<10; ++a)
      for (int b=0, c; b<10; ++b)
        if ((c=15-a-b) >= 0 && c < 10)
          Console.WriteLine(100*a + 10*b + c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Хорошее решение! Я такое же нашёл, лишнего перебора нет.

Comment: Только по моему должно быть `(c=15-a-b) >= 0`, и отсортировано не в том порядке.

Comment: Хотя в том порядке отсортировано.

Comment: `int b=0, c`, `(c=15-a-b) > 0` блин, ну зачем такому людей учить, ну раз уж решили нормальное решение выложить - зачем гольфить? Лишние скобочки неохота ставить?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, согласен, исправил.

Comment: @Андрей, `if ((int c = ...))` не компилируется :(

Comment: Не, конечно, потому что нужно добавить фигурные скобки и написать `int c = ...` на отдельной строчке

Comment: @Qwertiy, интересное решения, только не универсальное, если взять `10.000` работает уже не будет :(

Comment: @KillNoise, там нужно будет на рекурсию заменить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пробовал у меня не получилось

Comment: @KillNoise, задайте отдельным вопросом

Answer (score 2):

Еще один Linq-вариант, перебирающий 100 чисел:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n",
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 10)
            .Select(x => Enumerable
                .Range(0, 10)
                .Select(y => (x, y, z: 15 - x - y))
                .Where(t => t.z >= 0 && t.z <= 9))
            .SelectMany(t => t)
            .Select(t => t.x * 100 + t.y * 10 + t.z)));
```

Comment: Кстати, тоже хороший вариант!

Answer (score 2):

Вариант, который работает без полного перебора, третья компонента вычисляется на основе первых двух.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        int bMax = Math.Min(10, 16 - a);
        for (int b = Math.Max(0, 6 - a); b < bMax; b++)
        {
            int number = a * 99 + b * 9 + 15;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Протестировать можно тут - https://dotnetfiddle.net/EX9jVY

Comment: Можно еще сократить число итераций, если во втором цикле написать граничное условие что-то типа `b < 10 && b <= 15 - a`. Например, если a = 8, то смысла нету брать b = 8 или 9

Comment: @Андрей да, точно, думал про это но что-то зачитался вашего кода ))))) сейчас добавлю

Comment: Ваше решение, кстати, это "классический" итеративный вид моего Linq-монстра

Comment: Ну и начальное условие можно превратить в `int b = Math.Max(0, 6 - a)`, так если a = 0, то b заведомо не может быть равным 0, 1, 2 ...

Comment: @Андрей Ставлю вам лайк. Люблю задачи на алгоритмы, приятно их решать.

Comment: В итоге, если написать такой цикл: `for (int b = Math.Max(0, 6 - a); b < Math.Min(10, 16 - a); b++)`, то после вычисления `c` ее не нужно будет проверять вообще, она заведомо окажется в [0; 9]: `int number = a * 99 + b * 9 + 15; Console.WriteLine(number);`

Comment: Потом нужно `Math.Min(10, 16 - a)` вычислить перед циклом заранее и сохранить в переменную, чтобы каждую итерацию не проверялись условия. %) Тогда получим уже самый наибыстрейший вариант... наверное... ;)

Comment: @Андрей %).....

Comment: @Андрей если бы я мог бы вам дать бэдж за оптимизацию я бы вам его выдал ))

Answer (score 0):

int i = 999;

```
     while (i>0)   {
          int num = i;
```

int sum = 0;
for (int n = num; n > 0; sum += n % 10, n /= 10) ;

```
        if (sum == 15) 
        Console.WriteLine(i); 
        i = i-1;    

        }
```

вот так так думаю проще простого!!!! miysite.com  если что...

Comment: Я  думал отформатировать код проще простого!!! Но посмотрев ваше сообщение, засомневался.